# Iterating through an array and passing to another array

Tags: java, arrays

```
    static String[] TEST_NAMES = new String[]{"vectorTest",
    "scalarMultiplicationTest", "columnVectorTest", "dotProductTest",
    "matrixTest", "matrixMultiplicationTest", "selectRowTest",
    "selectMaxTest", "indexOfMaxTest", "updateTest", "addItemTest", 
    "updateDatabaseTest"};
```

I want a loop that would iterate through this array and whenever it points at an index in the testNames array it should pass it as an 'E' on to another array and the final array should be passed to a 'resultString' variable which returns all 'E's to the database. This is what I have tried but it has errors cos they are incompatible types.

```
          testNames = OOJavaBasics.TEST_NAMES;

         ArrayList<Integer> zeroSubmission= new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < testNames.length; i++) {
                if (thirdLastLine.contains("OK (0 tests)") && testNames.equals(i)){
                    zeroSubmission.add('E');
                    resultString = zeroSubmission;
                    System.out.println(resultString);
                }
            }
```

The output should be the total number which is 12 of the array length in E like this 'EEEEEEEEEEEE'

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. Your code also looks like it contains lots of pieces that are very specific to the assignment in question (e.g. what is OO.JavaBasics? thirdLastLine? etc). It would help if you reformat the code to distill it down to the actual problem you're trying to solve. Also, it looks like you're calling .equals on an array...is that even valid? You never declare resultString, but then assign to it an ArrayList...

Comment: @DanForbes OOJavaBasic is a java class. I have gotten rid of the thirdLastLine as it doesnt matter much cos ill add it later. The .equals doesnt work cos I am rubbish in programming lol thats why its on here for your help :)) resultString just send the variable to a database.

Comment: with `.equals()` we compare Strings and not Array or int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using only a String instead of having a second array.

Try the following:

```
     testNames = OOJavaBasics.TEST_NAMES;
     String resultString="";
        for (int i = 0; i < testNames.length; i++) {
            if (thirdLastLine.contains("OK (0 tests)") && testNames[i].equals("wanted result")){ // do not compare an Array with an int in the .equals()
                resultString += "E";
            }
        }
System.out.println(resultString);
```

Everytime you find the wanted result, you directly add an `"E"` to your `resultString`.

**EDIT:**

Referring to your last EDIT, the solution is very simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < testNames.length; i++) {
      resultString += "E";
}
```

Just loop through the array and add an `E` to the `resultString` in each iteration.

Comment: It crashed my web app

Comment: What's the error you get in console? and what's the ***Something***  you want to find ?

Comment: My console reportds everything but your piece of code which makes it go blank.

Comment: what do you mean by wanted result?

Comment: You said **whenever it finds something it should pass it as an 'E'** what's this something?? what do you want to test in your `if` statement?

Comment: check my last edit... I meant whenever it points at an index in the array it should return an E to indicate something is there

Comment: Okay, now it's clear. Take a look at my EDIT, you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
        String E = "";
        if (thirdLastLine.contains("OK (0 tests)")) {

            System.out.println(thirdLastLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < testNames.length; i++) {

                E += 'E';
            }
            resultString = E;

            System.out.println(resultString);
        }
```